# Should I release every time?

Tags: java, android, arrays, performance, optimization

### I was wondering if releasing my media player before I play a random sound is bad practice:

So I don't usually deal with media output too much, but I am making a simple app that plays a random sound every time a button is clicked **(`sounds []` is an array filled with raw media files)**

```
public void onClick(View v){

  if(mediaplayer != null){
    mediaplayer.release();
  }

   mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[randomNum])
   mediaplayer.start();

}
```

So my question is, would releasing my media player every time before creation be considered good/bad practice? Would there be any better way to do this, as releasing and re-initializing the MediaPlayer object seems like it would consume resources...

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: Do you expect to re-use the media player shortly after that sound? If so, then it's pretty pointless to dispose the resources, just to regather them soon after. Might aswell avoid the overhead. If the resources would be required elsewhere between the time you play different sounds, then release it. Otherwise, what's the point? You should profile your app, don't preoptimize.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Then how should I get a new random sound every click?

Comment: [MediaPlayer#selectTrack(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#selectTrack(int))

Answer (score 0):

You typically use release() when you no longer want to use a MediaPlayer any more.  Once you call that, it can never be used again.  It effectively destroys the native components that back its functionality.

If you do release, you will have to prepare the media all over again the next time you want to play it.  This can be a time consuming process.  If you want a sound to play responsively to a button press, you probably don't want to have to prepare it each time.